# flag specific pattern using string r

Tags: r, text, tidyverse, stringr

I am working with a data set where I need to flag all specific codes that start with "C13.xxx." There are other tree codes in the column and all tree codes are separated as follows: "C13.xxx|B12.xxx" - and all tree codes have a period in them. But the data set has other variables that are causing my string r function to flag characters that are not tree codes. Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# test data
test <- tribble(
  ~id, ~treecode, ~contains_c13_xxx,
  #--|--|----
  1, "B12.123|C13.234.432|A11.123", "yes",
  2, "C12.123|C13039|", "no"
)

# what I tried 
test  %>% mutate(contains_C13_error = ifelse(str_detect(treecode, "C13."), 1, 0))

# code above is flagging both id's as containing C13.xxx
```

in id 2, there is a variable that begins with C13, but it is not a tree codes (all tree codes have a period). The contains_c13_xxx variable is what I would like the code to produce. In the string detect function, I specified the period, so I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is there are multiple tree codes in the same column with a separator which makes it difficult to flag. We can bring each `treecode` into separate rows and then check for the code that we need. Using `separate_rows` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(treecode, sep = "\\|") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(contains_C13_error = any(startsWith(treecode, "C13.")),
            treecode = paste(treecode, collapse = "|"))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#     id contains_C13_error treecode                   
#  <dbl> <lgl>              <chr>                      
#1     1 TRUE               B12.123|C13.234.432|A11.123
#2     2 FALSE              C12.123|C13039|
```

This is assuming that there could be codes of the pattern "C13" without a dot. If the `treecode` would always have `"C13"` followed by a dot then simply escaping the dot in your regex would work.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Split on the | delim: 

split_treecode <- strsplit(df$treecode, "[|]")

# Roll out the ids the number of times of each relevant treecode: 

rolled_out_df <- data.frame(id = rep(df$id, sapply(split_treecode, length)), tc = unlist(split_treecode))

# Test whether or not string contains "C13" 

rolled_out_df$contains_c13_xxx <- grepl("C13.", rolled_out_df$tc, fixed = T)

# Does the id have an element containing "C13" ? 

rolled_out_df$contains_c13_xxx <- ifelse(ave(rolled_out_df$contains_c13_xxx,

                                             rolled_out_df$id,

                                             FUN  = function(x){as.logical(sum(x))}), "yes", "no")

# Build back orignal df: 

df <- merge(df[,c("id", "treecode")], unique(rolled_out_df[,c("id", "contains_c13_xxx")]), by = "id")
```

Data:

```
df <- 
  structure(
  list(
    id = c(1, 2),
    treecode = c("B12.123|C13.234.432|A11.123",
                 "C12.123|C13039|"),
    contains_c13_xxx = c("yes", "no")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-2L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```